OpportunityFieldHistory in Apex test class (field tracking - NewValue)
i'm new to learning about Apex Test Class.
I have business logic that needs to check the value of 'OpportunityFieldHistory' == 'ClosedWon' in a class to create a record (Contract).
I'm making a test class, however, I can't achieve 100% coverage because of this block of code:
    List<OpportunityFieldHistory> historyList = [SELECT CreatedDate, OldValue, NewValue 
                                                 FROM OpportunityFieldHistory 
                                                 WHERE OpportunityId = :params.oppId AND Field = 'StageName'
                                                 ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC];
    Date closedWonDate;
    for (OpportunityFieldHistory history : historyList) {
        if (history.NewValue == 'Closed Won') {
            closedWonDate = history.CreatedDate.date();
            break;
        }
    }

I saw this thread Is it possible to test apex that relies on field history tracking? which shows some implementation alternatives, however, I couldn't make it work.
This is my actual fail testing method:
@IsTest
static void testOpportunityHistoricFields() {
    Account acc = new Account(Name='Test Account');
    insert acc;

    Contact con = new Contact(LastName = 'Test Contact', AccountId = acc.Id);
    insert con;

    Product2 prod = new Product2(Name = 'Test Product', IsActive = true, Frequencia__c = 1, Validade__c = 12, TipoProduto__c = 'Contrato');
    insert prod;

    Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(Name='Test Opportunity', 
                                      StageName='Needs Analysis', 
                                      CloseDate=Date.today(), 
                                      AccountId=acc.Id, 
                                      ContactId=con.Id);
    insert opp;

    Test.startTest();
        opp.StageName = 'Closed Won';
        update opp;
    Test.stopTest();

    // Call the method to be tested
    OpportunityTriggerHandler.Params params = new OpportunityTriggerHandler.Params();
    params.oppId = opp.Id;
    params.installDate = Date.today();
    List<OpportunityTriggerHandler.Params> paramsList = new List<OpportunityTriggerHandler.Params>{params};
    List<OpportunityTriggerHandler.Result> results = OpportunityTriggerHandler.handleOpportunities(paramsList);

    // Verify the results
    List<OpportunityFieldHistory> historyRecords = [SELECT OldValue, NewValue, Field 
                                                    FROM OpportunityFieldHistory 
                                                    WHERE OpportunityId = :opp.Id];
    System.assertEquals(1, historyRecords.size()); // This assert FAILED.
}


Testing something involving History objects certainly wouldn't be my first choice for learning about testing.
100% coverage isn't really the goal. It's nice to have, but it's not necessary. It's far more important to cover a sufficient number of scenarios  and have meaningful assertions.
The general rules of unit testing are something like:

Have both positive and negative tests

e.g. "what happens when I call myWrappedInteger.divideBy(3)" (positive test, input and test environment are set up "correctly")
and "what happens when I call myWrappedInteger.divideBy(0) or
.divideBy(null)" (negative tests, input or test environment contains bad data on purpose)


Stress as little an amount of code as you can in each individual test
Test things that you have control over

Things like "is a history record created" isn't something you control, that's a feature Salesforce provides to us



Also, as noted in the question you linked, history records are not created in test contexts. So pretty much no matter what you do the System.assertEquals(1, historyRecords.size()); is never going to work
If you really need to get that coverage
It's been nearly 7 years since I wrote my answer on that question you linked. I think I'd take a different approach today.
Instead of trying to create history records, create and use a proxy class. It'd get used in the class that you're trying to test (instead of performing SOQL directly to get history records), and you'd inject data for it to return (in lieu of running a query) in your test method(s).
It doesn't need to be that complex. Something like the following would work just fine
public class OppFieldHistoryProxy {
    public String newValue;
    public Datetime createdDate;

    private static Map<Id, OppFieldHistoryProxy> historyProxyRecsByOppId = new Map<Id, OppFieldHistoryProxy>();

    public OppFieldHistoryProxy(String givenValue, Datetime givenDT) {
        newValue = givenValue;
        createdDate = givenDT;
    }

    // This is the method you'd call in your test class
    public static void setHistory(OppFieldHistoryProxy proxy, Id oppId) {
        List<OppFieldHistoryProxy> proxies = historyProxyRecsByOppId.get(oppId);

        if(proxies == null) {
            proxies = new List<OppFieldHistory>();
            historyProxyRecsByOppId.put(oppId, proxies);
        }

        proxies.put(proxy);
    }

    // This is the method you'd call in the "real" class instead of performing a query
    // Ideally, you'd want a method that could take a list of Ids
    //   so that the query only needs to be run once per transaction
    //   (if used in a place where you need to handle multiple ids at
    //   once)
    public static List<OppFieldHistoryProxy> getHistory(Id oppId) {
        List<OppFieldHistoryProxy> proxies = historyProxyRecsByOppId.get(oppId);

        if(proxies == null) {
            proxies = new List<OppFieldHistoryProxy>();
            // basically the same query that you have now
            for(OpportunityFieldHistory history : [SELECT CreatedDate, OldValue, NewValue 
                                                 FROM OpportunityFieldHistory 
                                                 WHERE OpportunityId = :oppId AND Field = 'StageName'
                                                 ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC]) {
                proxies.add(new OppFieldHistoryProxy(history.NewValue, history.CreatedDate));
            }
        }

        return proxies;
    }
}

You'd use it in your code like so
// The query above this line is completely removed, that's handled by the proxy
Date closedWonDate;

// Call the proxy instead of running the query
for (OppFieldHistoryProxy history : OppFieldHistoryProxy.getHistory(params.oppId)) {
    // The stuff inside the loop here is basically unchanged
    if (history.newValue == 'Closed Won') {
        closedWonDate = history.createdDate.date();
        break;
    }
}

and in your test method...
...
Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(Name = 'Test Opportunity', 
                                      StageName = 'Needs Analysis', 
                                      // Set a close date that isn't today
                                      //   so that you can assert that
                                      //   the CloseDate is updated by your code
                                      CloseDate = Date.today().addDays(-5), 
                                      AccountId = acc.Id, 
                                      ContactId = con.Id);
insert opp;

// Specifically create a proxy record for the test opp you're working with
// This will cause the code being tested to receive this data, but without
//   the need to run a query
OppFieldHistoryProxy.setHistory(
    new OppFieldHistoryProxy('Closed Won', Datetime.now()), testOpp.Id
);

Test.startTest();
    opp.StageName = 'Closed Won';
    update opp;
Test.stopTest();

Now, my example here isn't a complete solution, and can be tweaked/improved, but I hope it communicates the idea of how/why to use a proxy.
Yes, we've just moved the query from one location to another, and it's still basically impossible to completely test the query. However...

That detail now only exists in one class (as opposed to the query appearing in multiple classes, potentially)
Even if we can't get data out of the query in a test context, we can still cause the query to be run and thus gain coverage (not ideal, but we gotta play the hands we're dealt)
There's even a meaningful test that can be written for it (make sure that an Id for an Opp that doesn't exist, like 006000000000001, returns no rows)


Thanks for you explanation, Derek. I will study and try to implement this solution. Have a good day!
